# In the definition of linear map, is the symbol $+$ overloaded?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

On Wikipedia, the following definition of *linear map* is given:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over the same field $K$. A function $f:V\to W$ is said to be a *linear map* if for any two vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$ and any scalar $c\in K$, the following conditions are satisfied:
> \begin{align}
> f(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})&=f(\mathbf{u})+f(\mathbf{v}) \tag{*}\label{*}\\[5pt]
> f(c\mathbf{u})&=cf(\mathbf u)
> \end{align}

My question is: does the $+$ sign on the LHS of $\eqref{*}$ mean something different to the $+$ sign on the RHS? As far as I understand, on the LHS it denotes the vector addition operation of $V$, whereas on the RHS it denotes the vector addition operation of $W$, and these are not necessarily the same operation. Similarly, does $c\mathbf{u}$ refer to scalar multiplication in $V$, whereas $cf(\mathbf{u})$ refers to scalar multiplication in $W$?

Comment: You are absolutely right - in a more precise way one could write $f(u \oplus_V v) = f(u) \oplus_W f(v)$ and $f(c \cdot_V u) = c \cdot_W f(u)$.

Comment: Yes, if there was a potential for misunderstanding, one might choose to write something like $f(u+_V v)=f(u)+_W f(v)$.  Generally, though, context ought to clarify which addition is intended.

Comment: Worth noting:  this ambiguity (or, if you prefer, abuse of notation) occurs pretty widely.  A group homomorphism, for instance, is required to satisfy $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$ and nothing in that (standard) notation suggests that the product laws refer to the group laws in two different groups.

Comment: @lulu yes but in most texts they just overload it without mentioning anything.

Comment: @Asinomás  Yes, that's my point.  It is just taken for granted that readers will understand that the group law (be it written additively or multiplicatively) is always taken with respect to the relevant domain.

Comment: I had never even thought about this "issue" and none of my teachers mentioned it, even though some where "worried" about this sort of stuff.

Comment: Your use of the word overloaded perhaps indicates you’re familiar with its usage in computer programming languages. If so, I would say that the meaning of these plus signs is implied by strong type checking.

Comment: @Deane that makes sense ! Although there is also the more simple argument that they are using the same symbol for two different things (without alluding to other fields).

Comment: I wish the concepts of operator overloading and strong type checking were taught in math courses. These are important concepts when trying to read mathematical notation.

Comment: @Deane I guess I kind of agree with that, although I think the math preceeds the programming/compsci ( at least in a historical way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. There is a lecturer named Frederic Schuller who has done a mathematical treatment of GR in a set of publicly available Youtube lecture, and in it, he removed the ambiguity by adding subscripts under the addition symbol:

$$ f(u+_V v) = f(u) +_W f(W)$$

Comment: https://youtu.be/mbv3T15nWq0?t=1571 , time stamped